# Can anyone help me identify these swords?

Tags: identification, sword

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm not entirely sure what they are, but I don't want to give them up. They look really neat!

Comment: One of the things that usually helps is if you can provide accurate measurements of the items. Any background information on where they may have been obtained could be useful as well.

Comment: The long blade looks like a Japanese [katana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katana), but the length of the blade is important when trying to classify [Japanese swords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_sword#Length). I'm not sure if the absence of a guard on that blade is significant.

Comment: In general, images should be put onto imgur - we don't know what we're opening when we click a google drlive link.

Comment: The last couple of years or so the only luck I've had with images here is to download them to my PC and, click the add image button, click in the "Drag and drop or click here" area, and upload them that way.

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40540/where-and-when-is-this-sword-from/

Comment: The parts here definitely indicate a katana type weapon, but I can't find a match to the pattern on the menukis and kashira.

Comment: Please ask about each sword in a separate question, and [attach the images to your post directly](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3295/4935) instead of through urls. Also, in addition to the dimensions, please take a closer photo of the katana's sheath, especially of what looks like attachments near the opening. It looks like a tachi, though.

Comment: @Semaphore Can a person with rep=1 attach images? Has the rules on the stackexchange changed?

Comment: The sheath in images 4 &5 seems inappropriate for the blade.